# How to give an confirmation message to user before iframe gets unloaded?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In my application in main page a side menu is there clicking on which lead to loading of page in the center of the page. for a specific page i want to put such function that if it's loaded and any menu is clicked then it gives a message warning message to user to confirm if they really want  to use cancel.I can't use onbeforeunload event .Is there any other way by which it can be accomplished?

Comment: Why not `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: because it gives  a default message of the webpage says that. and i don't want that message.